# SSH connection problem after installing SSL in Google Cloud VM

Tags: ssl, ssh, gcloud

I installed SSL Let's Encrypt on Google Cloud VM and now I can't access SSH connection. I can't even access it via https://console.cloud.google.com. I checked the Firewall rules, and the documentation, but I couldn't find what caused this.

Comment: Let's Encrypt does not affect the SSH server directly. An incorrect setup might be causing the system to crash/fail. Use the serial console to review the startup logs: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-using-serial-console Update your question once you have more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the possible reasons why the VM instance have been inaccessible via SSH :

1. If there are no issues with the firewall rules, you can check if port 22 is open inside the VM instance. You can try using an [online port checker](https://portchecker.co/) to verify it.
2. After installing Let's Encrypt, your VM instance might have exhausted it's resources causing the service for port 22 to be terminated. I suggest you try rebooting/restarting the VM instance.
3. [Upgrade the machine type](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance) of your VM instance incase you encounter the issue re-occurs.

Comment: The problem was that port 22 was closed. For some reason the server was restarted ... I did't add `#! /bin/bash
sudo ufw allow 22` in the start script ...